# Empty bitmap when drawing from webview

Tags: android, canvas, webview, bitmap

i have a webview object in my project and i m trying to print html string on the webview . First time after loadData() and draw bitmap from it, bitmap renders correctl. But after that the bitmap always be empty until i clear app data.

Here is my code.

```
public void Print() {
    Webview mWebView = new WebView(activity);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(400);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    //mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           Bitmap myBitmap = createBitmapFromView();
           print(myBitmap);
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadData(mHtmlString, "text/HTML", "UTF-8");

}


public Bitmap createBitmapFromView() {
    mView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    mView.layout(0, 0, mView.getMeasuredWidth(), mView.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            mView.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    mView.draw(c);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: What is the use of this `createBitmapFromView()` method when you don't even use its returned `bitmap`?

Comment: @Darkman i edited the method. But the problem is, bitmap in createBitmapFromView()  empty until i clear app data.